# Machine Learning Python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, sklearn

Iniciei no curso de Machine Learning e no exercicio estou tendo dificuldade pois ele está me retornando um erro bobo que não consigo encontra a solução.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split #função de dividir dados de treino e teste
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
import numpy as np

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 1)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X1, Y1, random_state = 1)

knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4):

Você precisa ter os dados antes de separá-los nos dados de treino e teste.

Você está passando os dados de X1 e Y1 como parâmetro da função mas os dados não foram definidos ainda.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
>>> X1, Y1 = np.arange(10).reshape((5, 2)), range(5)
>>> X1
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7],
       [8, 9]])
>>> list(Y1)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

>>> X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X1, Y1, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa importar os dados separando os dados de treinamento e teste.

EX:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Data/seuarquivo.csv')

previsores = df.iloc[:,0:10].values

classe = df.iloc[:,4].values
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Acho que faltou voce importar os dados, vamos lembrar abaixo usando o pandas:
```

import pandas as pd

## No lugar do que esta entre aspas você coloca seu dataframe com o caminho onde está

df = pd.read_csv('Data/seuarquivo.csv')

## Separando aqui oque vai ser usado para prever e oque sera usado como classe ou o professor

previsores = df.iloc[:,0:4].values

classe = df.iloc[:,4].values

## Agora sim vou separar aqui os dados de teste e dados de treinamento

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(preditores,classes, test_size = 0.25, random_state=0)

## Agora vou importar o Knn, algoritimo que você esta usando

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

## Defino aqui alguns hyperparametros

classificador = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5, metric='minkowski', p=2)

## Treino o modelo

classificador.fit(X_train, y_train)

## Testo o modelo com minha base de teste, para ver se o modelo ficou bom

previsoes = classificador.predict(X_test)

## E agora vou verificar se ficou legal importando algumas metricas

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score
precisao = accuracy_score(X_test, y_test)
matriz = confusion_matrix(X_test, y_test)